# Zbar Python Library : Control camera resolution

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, zbar

I am using zbar python library on Raspberry Pi3 for scanning QR code.

I have USB camera mounted on /dev/video0.

I want to control camera resolution.
(Reduce resolution to improve performance)

I am not able to find any interface for same.

I have tried using `request_size` but  getting below error:

`zbar.Processor() object has no attribute 'request_size'`

Edit:

I am using `process_one` method.

Edit2:

Below is my code:

[image]

Comment: Example of the code that's causing the error might be helpful. You have to `request_size` before you call both `init` and `process_one` and AFTER you enable the processor with `parse_config('enable')`

Comment: @dbmitch please check the code

Comment: `Ask your USB webcam manufacturer !` Why ? Every USBCAM aren't same, `SET_RESOLUTION` is a `usb_host` message but you open with reading mode. Dump usbcam Set resolution command and resend with `pyusb` on starting reading to barcode...

Comment: [check this](http://superuser.com/questions/280607/vlc-stream-size) , [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214977/how-can-i-find-out-the-supported-webcam-resolutions),[this](http://elinux.org/Thread:Talk:Jetson/Cameras/How_to_do_I_change_the_USB_camera_resolution%3F/reply) @Vagish

Comment: @dsgdfg I am able to set resolution if I use C++ zbar libraries.